# Sorting users in Rails based on values in array attribute of user model

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have a User model which has an array inside of it. This array is used to store points the user has scored in various activities. It basically looks like this:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, fullname: "Kaja Sunniva Edvardsen", points: [0, 4170, 3860, 2504, 2971, 3859, 4346]>, #<User id: 2, fullname: "Alexander Lie Sr.", points: [0, 3273, 3681, 2297, 2748, 4202, 3477]>]>
```

I want to sort all Users by the different values in the points array to be able to create ranking list for each of the different activities, points[0], points[1], etc...

Sorting by points[1] should return Kaja first, 4170>3273, sorting by points[6] should put Alexander first, 4202>3859

How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to sort? Users or points or ? How do you sort - what is "by different values"? Can you give an expected outcome?

Comment: I want to sort the users by the values in the array. Something like OrderBy(points[1]) which doesn't work. The outcome I would want here would be Kaja first and Alexander second due to Kajas point[1] value being higher, 4170 vs 3273

Comment: What is the model definition and migration for users? How exactly you store an array in db?

Comment: Also, do you absolutely need to sort in DB or you can load all objects to Rails and sort there? How many objects will there be per one sorting group? Just thinking if there is a competition or something where you sort users by score, it shouldn't be too many users per comparison groups (thousands max? not millions)

Comment: I store it using ActiveRecord's serialize declaration like this in user model:
serialize :points

Migration: 
change_column :users, :points, :text, :default => [0]

Comment: Most likely not millions, 1000s or 10,000s, and I could load it to rails and sort it there. Didn't really find any good way of doing it that way either though.

Comment: My recommendation is to define an object representing entries in that array.  Then instead of relying on finding by index, you could assign a type to the scores and easily query with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, MySQL does not have an integrated array type.

Assuming you have a model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  serialize :points, Array
  # ...
end
```

You cannot sort with [`order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) queries, but you can try another solution (less efficient), handling the resources as an array:

```
User.all.sort { |user1, user2| user2.points[1] <=> user1.points[1] }
```

Which will return an array instead of an ActiveRecord query. Also, bear in mind that this code will not handle `nil` values (i.e. What if an user only have 2 elements in `points`?).

Comment: Thanks, yeah my model looks like that. I see, I get ArgumentError: comparison of User with User failed when I'm testing out this now but I'll try it out some more. Looks like I will sort it in Rails then so that's good to know.

Comment: Can you show us your current query to find debug it? :]

Comment: I had just missed a nil value. It does what I want, thanks for helping out!